# Boootstrap container design on arcgis javascript api map div

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am traying to use the bootstrap with arcgis javascript api. But I could not set the size of map div element 100% with and 100% height. The height is 400px; I tried set the css but not worked. [`example`](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/zz85h/) of application. And some pixels of map is under the navigation. I can not set the top of css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set any containers (html,body,.container,etc..) to 100% height also.

Also, the full-width container for Bootstrap 3.1 is `container-fluid`, so I changed your markup accordingly. The `row` is then used to eliminate the `container-fluid`'s outer padding.

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

.row,.container-fluid{
    height:100%;
}

#map{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zz85h/2/

Comment: Thanks for answer, I edited post. Some pixels of map is under the navigation bar.